# Database file space on drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to find out how much % of the space is being occupied by a particular SQL server database file(mdf/ldf) on a drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `<database-name>..sp_spaceused` procedure

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 1000.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk. You got it. Cheers